# Providing Access to a Whitelisted Server through OpenVPN

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

Ok, so there's a server A. This server is only accesible from another server B, with a given IP address. I want to install OpenVPN server on B so that clients connecting to this VPN can access server A as well.

If I understand correctly, the OpenVPN should be bridged, am I correct? Any advise on how to do this? An online tutorial maybe? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks,
Sammy

Answer (score 1):

If `ServerB` is only accessible from `ServerA`'s IP due to an ACL or policy-based route, then you'll need to configure `ServerA` as a L3 endpoint and enable NAT. This way, all requests from VPN clients will look like they are from `ServerA`